# How to get number of request in queue for selenium grid

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to figure a way to find the number of requests in a queue using selenium grid.

For example, If I have a grid with 8 chrome browser instances and I am trying to run 20 test cases in parallel in chrome, 12 requests go in selenium grid queue. This I can view on the grid [console](http://localhost:4444/grid/console), however, I was wondering if there is any API/method that I can call to check a number of pending request in a queue on the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `curl -X GET http://selenium_hub_host:4444/grid/api/hub/ -d '{"configuration":["newSessionRequestCount"]}'` to get the pending requests. Based on this you can use `httpclient` API in `java` as well.

Comment: it shows 0 but i have tests in queue.